# Не получается сделать выпадающий элемент sidebar

Tags: html, bootstrap

Я сделал боковую панель, но не получается добиться выпадания элементов после нажатия на одну из кнопок "Основы", "Разминка" или "Тренировка". Заранее спасибо за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <!-- <p>Dummy Heading</p> -->
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Основы</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu1">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Разминка</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu2">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Тренировка</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu3">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Т 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> Т 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Т 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в href у ссылок Вы забыли циферки добавить:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <!-- <p>Dummy Heading</p> -->
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Основы</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu1">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Home 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homeSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Разминка</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu2">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Р 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homeSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
            class="dropdown-toggle">Тренировка</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu3">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Т 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> Т 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Т 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @РусланМамедов, пожалуйста )